# How to setup Antminer D3 to solo mine to CANN wallet

Tags: altcoin, miner-configuration, solo-mining

I am trying to solo-mine CANN using my Antminer D3 directly to the full node wallet. I would really like to start adding decentralization to small coins just for the heck of it, but I am having some problems.

CANN wallet config:

> server=1 listen=1 rpcuser=u rpcpassword=x rpcport=39347
>   rpcallowip=10.0.0.* rpcallowip=* rpcallowip=10.0.0.214
>   rpcallowip=127.0.0.1

I have bfgminer set up as a getwork to stratum proxy via the following command:

> bfgminer -o 10.0.0.162:39347 -u u -p x --stratum-port=3333

However bfgminer is outputting this error:

> SSM: No usable 2D work upstream!

and my miner shows the pool as dead!

I know the miner is connecting to the bfgminer proxy because it displays this a few seconds after i set the ip in the miner interface:

> 0            |   0.0/  0.0/  0.0 h/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none

Full bfgminer output:

> bfgminer version 5.4.2 - Started: [2017-12-16 11:37:48] - [  0 days
>   00:04:52]  Pool 0: 10.0.0.162          Diff:256k  -GWork
>    LU:[11:41:48]  User:u  Block: ...9a1b9582e90dac52  Diff:256k (
>   1.83Th)  Started: [11:41:48]  I:?  ST:2  F:0  NB:3  AS:0  BW:[ 20/  7 B/s]  E:0.00  BS:0  0            |   0.0/  0.0/  0.0 h/s | A:0
>   R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
>
> ### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- NO DEVICES FOUND: Press 'M' and '+' to add

cross posted: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2598430.0

Comment: Stack Exchange [doesn't allow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty) payment to be offered for an answer.  I am editing that out of your question.

Comment: Also, your question would be much more readable if you use [preformatted text](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) for the config file excerpts and output, with line breaks in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

Try:(Change IP 192.168.1.147 to your and try same PC wallet and miner)

cannabiscoin.conf

```
server=1
listen=1
rpcuser=cannabisuser
rpcpassword=cannabispass
rpcport=39347
rpcallowip=192.168.1.147
addnode=seed.cannabiscoin.net
addnode=seed2.cannabiscoin.net
addnode=seed3.cannabiscoin.net
addnode=seed4.cannabiscoin.net
addnode=seed5.cannabiscoin.net
addnode=seed6.cannabiscoin.net
addnode=106.70.242.145
addnode=108.61.10.90
addnode=115.28.42.60
addnode=136.243.217.171
addnode=137.74.104.135
addnode=144.76.237.39
addnode=148.251.8.18
addnode=162.255.117.105
addnode=171.232.8.87
addnode=178.12.190.117
addnode=178.15.70.226
addnode=188.60.110.76
addnode=192.99.200.144
addnode=194.135.90.175
addnode=198.27.68.86
addnode=205.251.171.136
addnode=207.171.249.66
addnode=209.188.18.52
addnode=213.32.6.132
addnode=213.55.176.213
addnode=27.3.20.109
addnode=40.141.98.2
addnode=45.48.182.104
addnode=65.31.179.140
addnode=78.251.112.84
addnode=85.214.23.49
addnode=88.10.240.5
addnode=89.204.137.211
addnode=93.87.143.138
```

```
sgminer  https://github.com/sgminer-dev/sgminer

sgminer -o http://192.168.1.147:39347 -u cannabisuser -p cannabispass -I 13 -g 2 -w 256 --lookup-gap 2 --shaders 2048


cpuminer  https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi/releases

cpuminer-gw64-core2 -o http://192.168.1.147:39347 -u cannabisuser -p cannabispass
pause
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I cleaned up the formatting in your post to make it more readable. See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for more info on using Markdown.  Also, it is [not allowed to request payment in an answer](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/461/5757) so I edited out your coin address.  The asker shouldn't have offered payment and I am going to remove that also.

Comment: See for instance [preformatted text](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).